# Using Autoprefixer with notepad++

Tags: jquery, html, notepad++, autoprefixer

I am learning web design. I found a tool named **Autoprefixer**.
https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer
I use Notepad++ as my html and css editor. But I can't find a way to use **Autoprefixer** with Notepad++. Is there any plugin for Notepad++ ?
Or give me a suggestion how can I implement it in my web page.
Is there any jQuery plugin of **Autoprefixer** ? I know how to use jQuery plugins. just to add in a script tag in my html file.
Or please give me other suggestions that I will understand easily.
Thanx in advance.